# Ldap modify Attribute Java

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I am going mad over a LDAP attribute modification.
Be aware, I am very beginner so my code might contain mistakes and loads of issues but here is what I am trying to do.

I need to change the following attribute of a AD user `givenName`, `samAccountName`, `displayName` to the one of my choice.
I have 2 classes, one that searches for AD user (and works perfectly), and one that should modify the above attribute. However I keep getting error `InvocationTargetException`

This is Class 2, the one that does not work:

```java
     public void modify() {
        try {
         
         
            //connecting to the domain 
            Hashtable<String, String> ldapEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>(11);
            ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL,"TLSv1.2");
            ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"ldap://10.61.0.6:389");
            
            
            ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"CN=ldapadmin,OU=Users,OU=Dublin,OU=Europe,OU=Offices,DC=vmtech,DC=com");
            ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"Password1");
            InitialDirContext ldapContext = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv);
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv);
            
         
         System.out.println(NameObject);
            ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[3];
            //replace the GivenName
            Attribute A0 = new BasicAttribute("givenName", modgivenName);
            mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, A0);
            // replace the sAMAccountName
            Attribute A1 = new BasicAttribute("samAccountName", ModsAMAccountName); 
            mods[1] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, A1); 
            // Replace the displayname
            Attribute A2 = new BasicAttribute("displayName",ModdisplayName);
            mods[2] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, A2);
            
                     for(int i =0; i <= mods.length; i++){ 
                System.out.println(mods[i]);
                
            }
            // apply the modification to the object
            ctx.modifyAttributes(NameObject, mods);

                   
     
    } 
     
         catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LdapSearch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
         
     }
```

Comment: Adding the error stack will be helpful.

Comment: Hi Roshith thank you very much however i have fixed it.

Comment: Cool. You might want to update the answer section with the solution to  help others who face the similar issue.

Comment: Basically the ctx.modifyAttribute(nameObject, mods) only accept the DN of the Object

Comment: what is the nameObject?